# how to store the output of shell script in a log file inside a java class

Tags: java, shell

I am trying to call a shell script from a Java class and I want the output of the shell script to be stored in a log file.

My code looks something like this

```
String cmd = "/bin/sh /ws/priyapan-rcd/US248547/label_update.sh "+ branch_name + " "
   + product_type + " "
   + new_branch_name + " "
   + new_branch_label;
System.out.println("cmd is" +cmd);
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
try {
   p.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
   logger.error("{}", e);
}
//Gets the exit status to determine if label update was successful.
exitValue = p.exitValue();
// Sleeping for 500 milliseconds to give the script enough time to create the log files
Thread.sleep(500);
System.out.println("about to create the log file");
File LabelUpdateLog = new File("/ws/priyapan-rcd/workspace/labelupdate_"+train_id+".log");
//File LabelUpdateLog = new File("/users/ccmbuild/deactivation_cerebro/LabelUpdate_"+train_id+".log");

System.out.println("log file created");
logger.debug("{}", LabelUpdateLog);
```

all the print statements are getting executed but the log file is not generated.
can anyone please suggest the reason

i think this script is not getting called inside my class /ws/priyapan-rcd/US248547/label_update.sh
any idea why?someone please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You keep your code as is just change in command like

```
String cmd = "/bin/sh /ws/priyapan-rcd/US248547/label_update.sh "+ branch_name + " "
                                                                + product_type + " "
                                                                + new_branch_name + " "
                                                                + new_branch_label +" >>  LogFile.log";
```

If you want to create file on relative path then change your command accordingly.

```
String cmd = "/bin/sh /ws/priyapan-rcd/US248547/label_update.sh "+ branch_name + " "
                                                                + product_type + " "
                                                                + new_branch_name + " "
                                                                + new_branch_label +" >>  /ws/priyapan-rcd/workspace/labelupdate_"+train_id+".log";
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main things:

1. The constructor of the File class does not create on disk the file. It's just a file descriptor. If you want to create that file, you have to either call `labelUpdateLog.createFile()`
2. In your code I do not see where you try to write the "output of the shell script". You need to read the output stream of the process if you really want to get the output of the script.

By the way, the example in the [Javadoc of ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) simply states how to execute a command and save output to a log file.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
File log = new File("log");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
Process p = pb.start();
```